# How can I get rid of special characters in a text file? (Unix-like)

Tags: shell, gcc, text

I've got a source code file that started as a copy of some sample code from a webpage. It was created and edited under Windows and compiled without any problems.

But under [Macs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh), I get a load of obscure errors, like:

```
../MyProgram.cpp:1: error: stray '\255' in program
../MyProgram.cpp:1: error: stray '\254' in program
../MyProgram.cpp:1: error: stray '#' in program

../MyProgram.cpp:3:4: error: invalid preprocessing directive #i
../MyProgram.cpp:5:4: error: invalid preprocessing directive #i
../MyProgram.cpp:7:4: error: invalid preprocessing directive #i
../MyProgram.cpp:23: error: missing terminating ' character
../MyProgram.cpp:369:6: error: invalid preprocessing directive #i
../MyProgram.cpp:371:8: error: invalid preprocessing directive #i
../MyProgram.cpp:375:8: error: invalid preprocessing directive #e
../MyProgram.cpp:381:8: error: invalid preprocessing directive #e
../MyProgram.cpp:383:6: error: invalid preprocessing directive #e
../MyProgram.cpp:385:8: error: invalid preprocessing directive #i
../MyProgram.cpp:389:8: error: invalid preprocessing directive #e

../MyProgram.cpp:1: error: 'i' does not name a type
../MyProgram.cpp:53: error: 'V' does not name a type
../MyProgram.cpp:75: error: 'v' does not name a type
../MyProgram.cpp:157: error: 'l' does not name a type
../MyProgram.cpp:169: error: 'l' does not name a type
../MyProgram.cpp:187: error: 'i' does not name a type
../MyProgram.cpp:197: error: 'v' does not name a type
```

It looks like the problem is with some special characters.

How can I strip them off with a Unix-like command line?

Comment: under many distros of unix there is a dos2unix utility that should be under /usr/bin.  Not sure of OSX has that...

Comment: http://dos2unix.darwinports.com/

Comment: The issue isn't with special characters; it's with UTF-16: FFFE is your hint.

Comment: If the strays are in ***decimal*** (hexadecimal 0xFF 0xFE), [UTF-16LE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Byte-order_encoding_schemes) [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark): *"If the 16-bit units use little-endian order ("UTF-16LE"), the BOM is the (hexadecimal) byte sequence FF FE"*.

Comment: Are ***decimal*** stray numbers a signature of something or expected (GCC normally uses ***octal*** numbers)? Of [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang)? - *"In [Xcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) 3.2 and later, it included the Clang C/C++/Objective-C compiler ... based on LLVM.". [Xcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#3.x_series): "Xcode 3.2 was released with [Mac OS X v10.6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Snow_Leopard) (Snow Leopard)"*. Mac OS X v10.6 was released 2009-08-28. Though this question was submitted before that date.

Comment: Related (but is at the current time mostly about actual special characters): *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332/)*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks to me as if the file was saved as [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16). Opening it in a text editor and re-encoding to UTF-8 should, with some luck, fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Originally, I was just going say how to remove the \255 and \254 characters, but I agree with the comments. It's in [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).

Try to convert it with [iconv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv):

```
iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 infile > outfile
```

`iso-8859-1` is just a guess.